# Concatenate and sort arrays using a list in Python

Tags: python

Here is my problem:

I have created two lists: max_idx and min_idx.

I have combined and sorted them to one: idx.

I have created two np.arrays that use the max_idx and min_idx.

I did concatenate these arrays and now I want to sort them according to the idx.

Please, see the example below:

```
max_idx = [4, 31, 72, 97]
min_idx = [18, 43, 67]

idx = max_idx + min_idx
idx.sort()
idx = [4, 18, 31, 43, 67, 72, 97]

high_peaks = hi.values[max_idx] = array([1, 2, 3, 4])
low_peaks = lo.values[min_idx] = array([-5, -6, -7])

peak = np.concatenate((high_peaks, low_peaks)) = array([1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -6, -7])
```

I am missing the last step which is this:

```
peaks.sort(idx) = array([1, -5, 2, -6, -7, 3, 4])
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If you are looking for how to extract from a numpy array by indices, then perhaps this will help: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
max_idx = [4, 31, 72, 97]
min_idx = [18, 43, 67]
high_peaks = [1, 2, 3, 4]
low_peaks = [-5, -6, -7]

paired_list = list(zip(max_idx, high_peaks)) + list(zip(min_idx, low_peaks))
# [(4, 1), (31, 2), (72, 3), (97, 4), (18, -5), (43, -6), (67, -7)]
paired_list.sort(key=lambda p: p[0])
# [(4, 1), (18, -5), (31, 2), (43, -6), (67, -7), (72, 3), (97, 4)]
sorted_by_idx = [value for _, value in paired_list])
# [1, -5, 2, -6, -7, 3, 4]
```

First zip the indices and values together in pairs of (idx, value), then sort by index and finally extract the values.